# What's the difference between the media queries max-width and max-device-width?

Tags: css, media-queries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between max-device-width and max-width for mobile web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web)

For instance, this website:

http://8faces.com/ uses **max-width**.

[This](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) tutorial uses **max-device-width**:

Example:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .column {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

What's the difference between them? Do they work in Android, iOS, iPad, etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check this post. http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/combining_meta.html

Comment: +1 This just resovled my doubt. We should always include that meta tag.

Answer (score 4):

`max-device-width` will target devices(iphone/ipad), as `max-width` will target screens(browsers).

Hope this helps