# Recommended widths for responsive layouts

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

What do you recommended should be the widths I should use for a responsive layout?

```
  /* Default Width: */
  .container { width: 940px; margin: 0 auto; }

  /* Smaller than standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {}

  /* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {}

  /* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}

  /* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
  @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {}

  /* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {}
```

Comment: What is your question? In your listing are some good values in my opinion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good widths for media queries on responsive site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564752/good-widths-for-media-queries-on-responsive-site)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, did you flag it as such?  I did so yesterday, but I think it takes several duplicate flags by the community to get reviewed by SO moderators.

Comment: @hotshot309 I voted to close it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no **recommended** width for responsive layout. It's totally depends upon your layout structure. `Layout Structure` means use **MEDIAQUERIES** when you want any specific changes on an specific width or when your layout broke any specific screen width.

Answer (score 46):

I've started using "320 and up"'s widths which are as follows:

Note that they go from small to large not the other way around though. This is more in line with progressive enhancement and definitely preferred anyway:

- [Brad Frost - mobile-first responsive web design](https://bradfrost.com/blog/post/mobile-first-responsive-web-design/)
- [stuffandnonsense.co.uk - 320 and Up](https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/320-and-up)

```css
// Default styling here

// Little larger screen
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {

}

// Pads and larger phones
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {

}

// Larger pads
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

}

// Horizontal pads and laptops
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {

}

    // Really large screens
@media only screen and (min-width: 1382px) {


}

// 2X size (iPhone 4 etc)
@media only screen and 
        (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and 
        (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2), only screen and 
        (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}
```

If you use Sass, here's a little trick I've been using:

```
$laptop-size: "only screen and (min-width: 768px)";
$desktop-size: "only screen and (min-width: 1382px)";
// etc
```

And then

```css
@media #{$laptop-size} {
    // Styling here...
}
```

This way you can easily change widths in one place also you don't have to write the whole thing every time.

Comment: Can you please help me understand why did you use min-width instead of the traditional max-width that I often see?

Comment: I think Brad Frost explains it better: http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/web/mobile-first-responsive-web-design/. In short, starting from the lowest common denominator ensures that it works everywhere. Just like how you first build a fully functional HTML form and _then_ "hijax" it for browsers that understand it. This is called progressive enhancement. Going the other way is graceful degradation and really has zero benefits over PE.

Comment: Very good answer, although a little information as to why those widths were chosen by 320-and-up would be nice.

Comment: @powerbuoy is your answer still true in 2018? ps. the `http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/` is broken

Comment: @Flo personally I just break when it's needed. To keep things consistent I normally store my numbers in SASS variables but I rarely care about specific devices tbh. Can't wait for element queries or whatever they'll be called.

Comment: @powerbuoy thank you. Do you have a code sample available online perhaps? I'm starting out with CSS grids and am looking for code that has worked well in production.

Comment: There are so many examples of this, one of which in my own reply with SASS vars (I still use that approach) I recommend reading Frost's article as well. It's still as relevant today.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for best/common practices and particular widths applied when using responsive layouts, I'd suggest you look into *grid systems* readily available. A quick google search yields a lot of results, but one of my favourite ones would be the 1140 grid from cssgrid.net (site no longer available) - I very much agree with their logic on choosing the measurements. Verbatim:

> The 1140 grid fits perfectly into a 1280 monitor. On smaller monitors
>   it becomes fluid and adapts to the width of the browser.
>   Scrap 1024! Design once at 1140 for 1280, and with very little extra
>   work, it will adapt itself to work on just about any monitor, even
>   mobile.

If this is not the kind of answer you were looking for, please rephrase the question.

Comment: The problem is I want it to be responsive, but I don't want it to be fluid. That's why I thought of settings individual widths for each screen size.

Comment: I think for anything smaller than ~900px it's better to be fluid. There are so many different hand held devices out there that you'll end up with hundreds of different media queries otherwise.