# Common CSS Media Queries Break Points

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am working on a Responsive Web Site with CSS Media Queries.

Is the following a good organization for devices?
Phone, Ipad (Landscape & Portrait), Desktop and Laptop, Large Screen

What are the common media queries break-point values?

I am planning to use the following breakpoints:

- 320: Smartphone Portrait
- 481: Smartphone Landscape
- 641 or 768 ???: IPad Portrait ???
- 961: IPad Landscape / Small Laptop ???
- 1025: Desktop and Laptop
- 1281: Wide Screen

What do you think? I have a few doubts as ??? points.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8564752/3597276

Answer (score 198):

Rather than try to target @media rules at specific devices, it is arguably more practical to base them on your particular layout instead. That is, gradually narrow your desktop browser window and observe the natural breakpoints for your content. It's different for every site. As  long as the design flows well at each browser width, it should work pretty reliably on any screen size (and there are lots and lots of them out there.)

Comment: I agree but I would like to have a few references to work around it ... I just updated initial text. I added breakpoint values. What do you think? I am still not sure about 641 / 768 / ...

Comment: As I mentioned, if you try to chase screen sizes you'll get overwhelmed, as there are many of them. Let your layout dictate where the breakpoints need to be. You may only need one or two. :)

Comment: Responsive not Adaptive is indeed the right buzzword direction to head in. Agree with you Ralph. (But also understand helping legacy systems be reasonably mobile with stopgap breakpoints is often a necessity.)

Comment: This is spot on and should be the accepted answer. There are no 'common' screen sizes.

Comment: here's a great article outlining why this is a bad way to go about the problem and how you should approach multi device css: http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer and the default approach to media queries. It's way less exhaustive to have a few media queries setup on natural breakpoints than it is to use a myriad of arbitrary ones.

Comment: Blog post linked in a comment here goes to 404, I believe the new URL is https://bradfrost.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/

Answer (score 101):

I've been using:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* tablets and desktop */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    /* phones */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    /* portrait phones */
}
```

It keeps things relatively simple and allows you to do something a bit different for phones in portrait mode (a lot of the time I find myself having to change various elements for them).

Comment: Where do you place ipad there? And what if you have a desktop with a large screen?

Comment: The ipad is in `min-width: 768px`. If you have a desktop with a large screen then you can go ahead and add something like `@media only screen and (min-width: 1176px)`. What I put in my answer is the media queries I find myself using the most.

Comment: I have also found this: http://alpha.responsivedesign.is/develop/media-queries/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints. But it seems to much for a simple web site.

Comment: It depends if you want to show high-resolution images for retina displays with the help of `background-size` or not. If you do, then you will need separate media queries that detect `min-device-pixel-ratio`.

Comment: could you link to mockup.  i fail to see how 767px works with phones

Comment: @b_dubb unfortunately I don't have anything to hand - all of my recent sites have been internal only jobs :(

Comment: @boz Thanks for this. I didn't use it exactly as shown in your answer, but it pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 97):

I'm using 4 break points but as ralph.m said each site is unique. 
You should experiment. There are no magic breakpoints due to so many devices, screens, and resolutions.

Here is what I use as a template. 
I'm checking the website for each breakpoint on different mobile devices and updating CSS for each element (ul, div, etc.) not displaying correctly for that breakpoint.

So far that was working on multiple responsive websites I've made.

```
/* SMARTPHONES PORTRAIT */
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {


}

/* SMARTPHONES LANDSCAPE */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {


}

/* TABLETS PORTRAIT */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {


}


/* TABLET LANDSCAPE / DESKTOP */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {


}
```

**UPDATE**

As per September 2015, I'm using a better one. I find out that these media queries breakpoints match many more devices and desktop screen resolutions.

Having all CSS for desktop on style.css

All media queries on responsive.css: all CSS for responsive menu + media break points

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px){ ... }

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px){ ... }

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){ ... }

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px){ ... }
```

**Update 2019:** As per Hugo comment below, I removed max-width 1999px because of the new very wide screens.

Comment: Does that mean you use defaults for width > 1999?

Comment: I would remove (max-width: 1999px) and let everything above 992px fit in this rule.

Answer (score 55):

This is from css-tricks [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: That's ... *a lot.*

Comment: Yeah, my trick is I created a mixin in saas and use it whereever I need it. :-)

Comment: Thanks, this helped

Answer (score 18):

I can tell you I am using just a single breakpoint at 768 - that is `min-width: 768px` to serve tablets and desktops, and `max-width: 767px` to serve phones.

I haven't looked back since. It makes the responsive development easy and not a chore, and provides a reasonable experience on all devices at minimal cost to development time without the need to fear a new Android device with a new resolution you haven't factored in.

Comment: Don't confuse pixels with points. Phones at high density (aka retina) screens still report the lower resolution. Here is a nice little CSS gist that may add some hints https://gist.github.com/levibuzolic/947778

Comment: Well, according to this site http://nmsdvid.com/snippets/, Galaxy S2 is 320x533 - so I am not sure how you saw a desktop version. Did you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />` in your `<head>` ?

Answer (score 12):

**Media Queries for Standard Devices**

In General for Mobile, Tablets, Desktop and Large Screens

**1. Mobiles**

```
 /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 480px) {

    /* Styles */

    }
```

**2. Tablets**

```
@media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) {

         /* Styles */

    }
```

**3. Desktops & laptops**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {

    /* Styles */

}
```

**4. Larger Screens**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {

    /* Styles */

}
```

**In Detail including landscape and portrait**

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 321px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (max-width : 320px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Tablets, iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Tablets, iPads (landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : landscape) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Tablets, iPads (portrait) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : portrait) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 1224px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Large screens ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 1824px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* iPhone 4 ----------- */
    @media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
    /* Styles */
    }
```

Reference

Answer (score 11):

Consider using [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)'s break points.
with such a massive adoption rate you should be safe...

Comment: For the lazy. <768, <992, <1200, >=1200.

Comment: Really hate their sm, md, lg system! Not understandable for me! Especially when it comes to column resets. And, your suggestion make mandatory to use bootstrap on your design.

Comment: @AdrianP.  You can customize Bootstrap on their site and just download a css file to use only the grid system, doing this you aren't forced into their design.

Comment: in BOOTSTRAP 4 they have extended breakpoints: XS:0 (Extra small screen / phone), SM:544px (Small screen / phone), MD:768px (Medium screen / tablet), LG:992px (Large screen / desktop), XL:1200px (Extra large screen / wide desktop)

Comment: "with such a massive adoption rate you should be safe" - disagree 100%. use != value. bootstrap makes developers lives easier, but that doesn't make the product better. bootstrap was horrible for accessibility for the longest time.

Answer (score 9):

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) {/*--- Mobile portrait ---*/}
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) and (max-width : 595px) {/*--- Mobile landscape ---*/}
@media only screen and (min-width : 595px) and (max-width : 690px) {/*--- Small tablet portrait ---*/}
@media only screen and (min-width : 690px) and (max-width : 800px) {/*--- Tablet portrait ---*/}
@media only screen and (min-width : 800px) and (max-width : 1024px) {/*--- Small tablet landscape ---*/}
@media only screen and (min-width : 1024px) and (max-width : 1224px) {/*--- Tablet landscape --- */}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you go to your google analytics you can see which screen resolutions your visitors to the website use:

Audience > Technology > Browser & OS > Screen Resolution ( in the menu above the stats)

My site gets about 5,000 visitors a month and the dimensions used for the free version of [responsinator.com](http://responsinator.com) are pretty accurate summary of my visitors' screen resolutions.

This could save you from needing to be too perfectionistic.

Answer (score 4):

I always use Desktop first, mobile first doesn't have highest priority does it? IE< 8 will show mobile css..

```
normal css here: 

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {}
```

sometimes some custom sizes. I don't like bootstrap etc.

Comment: It is time to stop developing for IE < 8, and for many sites, mobile should have first priority.

Comment: Agree, but thats not the main reason I use desktop first

Comment: Apparently I had a strong opinion about this on March 19, 2015 :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using pixels should use em or percentage as it is more adaptive and fluid, better not target devices target your content:

[HTML5 rockrs read, mobile first](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/#toc-style-mobilefirst)

Answer (score 3):

Keep your code clean and stylesheets logically separated per screen 'media' type config... 


1) Using himansu's answer from above as a reference: [Common CSS Media Queries Break Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443380/common-css-media-queries-break-points/23884178#23884178)
AND
2) https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

your answer would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px)" href="mobilePortrait.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" media="@media only screen and (min-width : 481px) and (max-width : 595px)" href="mobileLandscape.css">
```

Comment: Is the first media string supposed to be missing the `@`?

Comment: Thanks RaginRoosevelt --> not supposed to be missing the @.  I've edited as required for future generations - thanks for checking!

Comment: why making two https request ??? we can simply put them in one file , isn't that cool ???

Comment: Thanks Ellisson... fair point.  But don't modern browsers aggregate the the calls these days!

Answer (score 2):

Your break points look really good. I've tried `768px` on Samsung tablets and it goes beyond that, so I really like the `961px`.
You don't necessarily need all of them if you use responsive CSS techniques, like `%` `width/max-width` for blocks and images (text as well).