# What resolutions should I code for?

Tags: html, css, web-applications, screen-resolution

I need a list of desktop and mobile resolutions that I should code for.

I am making a page with `no-scroll` and `overflow: hidden;` So I need to adjust the page for each `desktop resolution` and `mobile resolution`, so I just need a list if possible please.

Comment: What resolutions are your users using? Generally, your site should look well on all reasonable resolutions. If you structure your CSS correctly then you shouldn't have to add support for a specific resolution

Comment: You can look for `twitter-bootstrap` responsive designs.

Comment: There's alot of resolution .. with different pixelrate .. portrait and landscape...

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to target specific resolutions. Especially on a desktop the browser window can be any size and at any zoom level and on any size screen so there really aren't any standard dimensions.

Comment: What Juhana said, design fluid so your site looks good at all resolutions and use media queries to correct the layout when required

Comment: http://designshack.net/articles/css/responsive-design-why-youre-doing-it-wrong/ and http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8564752/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/) for [**Media Queries for Standard Devices**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/). This includes portrait and landscape layouts.

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

There are also many online snippets for the same available:

1. [Common @media queries](http://www.smipple.net/snippet/joost.kiens/Common%20@media%20queries)
2. [Media queries for common device breakpoints](http://alpha.responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints)
3. [Responsive Web Design: Layouts and Media Queries](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/04/23/responsive-web-design-layouts-and-media-queries/)
4. [Common CSS Media Queries Break Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443380/common-css-media-queries-break-points)

Answer (score 0):

Use responsive CSS by @media query .. like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .container {width: 100%;}   
    .dropdown {height:35px;}
    .dropdown p {line-height:35px;}
    .header {height:40px; background:url(images/logoplastik.png) no-repeat 10px 90% left center ;   }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    .container {width: 100%; }
    .dropdown {height:35px;}
    .dropdown p {line-height:35px;}
    .header {height:40px; padding-left:10px;}
}
```