# Center images when window is resized

Tags: html, css

I'm displaying a lot of images. When the window is resized, I want to be able to center the number of images fits within the window. currently it aligns to the left when when the browser window is resized.

```
li {
    float:left; 
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.itemS{
    max-width:1366px;   
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.itemS.itemType{
    width: 250px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#333;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    text-align:center; 
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML? (Simplified)

Comment: <div class="itemS"><li><div class="itemType"><input type="image" src=1stimge.jpg/><gt_descA>1st description</gt_descA></div></li></div></div>

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is CSS Media Queries. You set breakpoints in the queries, and when the browser window is larger or smaller than the breakpoint, your new styles are applied.

If this is your initial style:

```
li {
    float:left; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You may want to change the div when the browser window is below 768, you change styles this way:

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    li {
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Read more at [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) or in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443380/common-css-media-queries-break-points).

Hope this can get you on the way! Good luck!