# Web page alignment changes when Android keyboard open

Tags: android, joomla, keyboard, html

On my website in mobile, the responsive layout broken when Android keyboard open. I am using the Joomla framework. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided very much information but my guess is that the keyboard is messing up the breakpoints in the CSS. Here is a good place to read more about breakpoints and how people are using them: [Common CSS Media Queries Break Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443380/common-css-media-queries-break-points). In the future you need to provide a lot more information in order for people to help you.

Comment: problem is that , when i click on text box the android keyboard opens and it is moving the contents on pages upward and breaks all the layouts..