# HTML table changes colors and format when reducing window size

Tags: html, html-table, size, responsive

I have a HTML table that for some reasons suddenly changes its colors and formatting whenever the webpage gets very small or it's being displayed on a mobile device.

Here's the initial table:

[image: Table on regular screen size]

And that's how it looks like after reducing the size:

[image: Table on mobile device or small screen.]

It's a simple HTML table, nothing special to it. It's embedded on a Wordpress page on two different locations. Here are the two URLs, maybe that helps!

https://www.akkordeonorchester-muenchen.de/news/

https://www.akkordeonorchester-muenchen.de/kartenbestellung/

```html
<table style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Bitte beachten Sie folgende Zeiten für unseren Konzerttag:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tageskasse &amp; Garderobe</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">ab 13:00 Uhr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Saaleinlass</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">13:15 Uhr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Konzertbeginn</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">14:00 Uhr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Konzertende</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">ca. 16:30 Uhr</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use CSS Media Queries. check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443380/common-css-media-queries-break-points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed any wordpress plugin related to responsive table such as "automatic responsive tables" plugin. This effect to table is done by that plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just took that website over and it's a total mess.. so many plugins, I had no clue about that one! Thank you!