# What is today's most popular screen resolution?

Tags: screen, viewport, resolution, screen-resolution

Is there a place that displays statistics in such a manner that I can rely on? e.g. Google/Microsoft homepage screen size statistics? An international statistics organization that checks multiple websites to come up with a more accurate number?

Comment: There is no conflict, you just did not read that it It says 97% for "1024x768 **or higher**."

Comment: In terms of responsive design, it shouldn't matter: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8564752/3597276

Comment: So, if a web designer asks you to which resolution they should aim for you would say it doesn't matter? what would be the base resolution for their design?

Comment: There are couple websites that list most of the devices' viewport sizes, and I have made a [repository](https://github.com/akinuri/common-screen-dimensions) that calculates the most frequent dimensions (by device).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Google previously had a tool at ***browsersize.googlelabs.com*** which is now shut down. Not sure that Microsoft currently shares this type of data either.

Here are a couple popular website statistics plugins used on a large number of websites that publish aggregated statistics which might be helpful:

http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php

http://gs.statcounter.com/#resolution-ww-monthly-201412-201505

From these charts you can see that no screen resolution individually makes up a majority of users as it might have in the past. Even the resolution with the highest share (1366x768) does not break the 30% mark in either of these statistics websites. Statistics from websites that I work on support these results as well.

I assume you are looking into browser sizes for the purpose of web design/development. In recent years the focus has turned towards responsive web design (RWD) due to the ever increasing usage of smartphones and tablets to access the web.  Designing for just one particular resolution is not as viable as it was in the past because of this.

Comment: responsive design is fine, but what the screens vary from 320px in width (iphone 5, 4" phone) to 1920px in width (1080p, 23" monitor), then responsive becomes a big challenge. It is fine when sticking with smaller combinations and a fixed 980px website, but getting larger than that requires more.

Comment: w3c has irrelevant data, because they count ALL - desktop, mobile, maybe even TV. Is there statistics exactly for DESKTOP?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you mean resolution, not screen size, and it may not be a relevant datum nowadays.

I'd say that most popular resolution is actually somewhere between 240*320-ldpi and 1080*1920-xxhdpi which are smart-phone resolutions.

As for desktop computer's resolutions, you can find [statistics](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp) in the [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp) website, updated from 2000 to 2015.

In any case, think **responsively**, **good front-end design should work in any screen size**, from intelligent watches to stadium plasmas.

Comment: Of course, I'm just looking for reliable information. :)

Comment: intelligent watches? are you serious? how do you want to navigate through that?

Comment: You obviously have to adapt to the circumstances. My boss is reading his emails on gmail right now on his watch. I wouldn't expect him to actually write one though.

Answer (score 1):

There are two measurements at work here, screen resolution (the physical hardware/software combination of what the screen is capable of) and the Viewport size, what Google calls the "Browser Size" (which is now available as a variable in Google Analytics. Comparing Screen Resolution with Browser Size is quite insightful. I don't think Screen Resolution is helpful for the web, as the web is really about a browser window and what you can do with that. Especially on the desktop, many do not use a browser window full-screen.