# media queries and firefox/chrome

Tags: iphone, css, media-queries

Hi so I have a media query that gets picked up by ios simulator

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="css/iphone.css">
```

What I would like to do is simulate this on firefox or chrome by resizing the browser, is this possible?

Comment: It is indeed. Just resize your browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/iphone.css" media="all and (max-width: 480px)" />
```

Comment: Maybe I didnt understand original question, but...
I understood that he what use css/iphone.css in chrome/firefox if window is resized under 480px.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `max-width`. `max-device-width` is the physical screen size so that won't change. See: [What is the difference between max-device-width and max-width for mobile web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web)

However, that won't fully solve your problem for iOS because Safari reports a width (but not a device-width) of 980px by default, so pages not designed for mobile appear as a full zoomed-out page. So, you also need to add something like this to your HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0">
```

You can find a reference from Apple on viewport settings here: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can directly simulate this on Firefox and chrome. But Firefox doesn't support media queries below 480.

You can also check the below link for re-size in Firefox & chrome.
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/

Hope This Helps