# Can I visualise media queries in Firefox like in Chrome?

Tags: css, firefox, media-queries, visualization

Can I have something like this in Firefox/Firebug? I mean those colored lines under the rulette of resulutions - without this I can't use Firefox for editing CSS with media queries.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [media queries and firefox/chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010283/media-queries-and-firefox-chrome)

Comment: No, this question is about visualisation, not about simulating width.