# why can't I target smart phone vs. not smart phone with responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to define css for smart phone, and everything else in my CSS can be as-is.

Css:

```
.content { background: orange; padding: 30px; }
#mobile { display:none; }

@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px){
    #mobile { display: block; }
    #desktop { display: none; }
}
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="mobile">this is mobile</div>
  <div id="desktop">this is desktop</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L5zDQ/

If you make the browser window shrink w/ the demo above, "this is mobile" never shows up.  What am I missing?

Comment: What is this "smart phone" you speak of?

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `max-device-width` you should be using `max-width`, which is subject to the size of the browser's current state:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

max-device-width is the size of your *screen*, it does not change when you resize the window.

What you want is `max-width` which compares to the size of the browser window;

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    #mobile { display: block; }
    #desktop { display: none; }
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web) for a little more discussion on the topic.