# Testing media queries

Tags: css, cross-browser, media-queries

Ive written some media queries as bellow, but when im trying to test them it seems that they are not working, am i correct in thinking that the media query tests for the screen dimensions rather than the browser dimensions ?

If so how can you test if the media queries are working as im on a laptop 15", connected up to a 22" external display, and the styles i want to test are for screens sub 1300px ie. 13"  and bellow

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 500px) 
and (max-device-width : 1300px)  {          

    h1      {font-size:90px; margin-bottom: 60px;}

    h2      {font-size:27px; padding: 0 0 20px 0; }

    p       {font-size:18px; -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;}

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web

Comment: Media queries watch viewport (browser viewable area) dimension, not screen (monitor) dimension.

Answer (score -3):

Media queries don't match screen size -- they match browser size. Just resize the window.

There are tools for this [in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View) and the same things are in Chrome too.

Comment: media queries can match both.. max-width: will match the browser, max-device-width: will match the screen