# Media Queries inside styles not getting affect the design

Tags: html, css

I am developing screen for iphone & android mobile using HTML5,CSS3.

Whatever style I written inside of media queries its not affecting my design. Suppose I place those style outside of media queries its working fine..

Please let me know the reason..

Here I given my jsFiddle sample code..

```
<body>
<header>
  <div> <img src="images/Uconnect_header.png" width="480" height="114"> </div>
</header>
<section> 
    <div id="headingTxt"><h5>UCONNECT ACCESS SERVICES</h5></div>
    <p class="descriptionTxt">Services intro copy will go here and need to be dynamically filled according to new and existing schemas. This could be larger or smaller then what is displayed here.</p>
    <hr>


body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    width:480px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
section{
    margin:10px;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

    #headingTxt{background-color:#009966;}
    .descriptionTxt{color:red;}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prabunivas/dkdRt/

Answer (score 0):

try this one `@media (max-width: 480px) { ...`

to be able to check with browser resizing while developing.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web) for differences between max-width and max-device-width

Comment: doesn't it play in the jsfiddle? I just tried it to the one you provide and I can see the colors change when I resize the window

Comment: I tried with resize also its not happening for me.. This two style inside the media queries ( #headingTxt, .descriptionTxt)..