# What does this line of CSS mean? @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px)

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I found the following line of code inside Wordpress' Twenty Eleven theme stylesheet.

What does it mean?

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px)
```

Comment: Take a look at this website: http://responsivedesign.ca/resources

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between max-device-width and max-width for mobile web?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web)

Comment: Google is your best friend. Afterwords come to us...

Comment: @Bram: I just googled this, and this question was the top result. I often find SO gives quicker access to what I need to know than the original documentation. I guess it's a high-level goal question of what SO is for--but as far as I'm concerned, questions like this are very useful.

Comment: @BramVanroy, Cephron is right. This is actually a useful question. I always search Google and then look for Stack Overflow answers. This is exactly what happened in this case and the accepted answer provided exactly the info I needed. Isn't the point of SO to ask and answer questions???

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's called [**CSS3 Media Queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries) which is a technique to help your website adapt to various of screen dimensions or basically, it helps to deliver different styles to different devices.

Since you're new, let's break down your media query to two parts:

```
@media only screen
```

This means we will apply css styles to a device with a screen. The keyword `only` used here to hide style sheets from older browsers from seeing phone style sheet.

```
and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px)
```

This is quite obvious since it means that the specified css **only** applied when a device has a screen's size with minimum `320px` and maximum of `480px` in width dimension.

Comment: Yeah but then what? Do I write my css classes after that line or what?

Comment: `@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {` _// CSS styles in here that you only want applied to the above_ e.g. h1 { font-size: 3.0em; } `}`

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand the meaning of code step by step:

You code was:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px)
```

The **@media** rule is used to define different style rules for different media types/devices.

The **only** keyword prevents older browsers that do not support media queries with media features from applying the given styles. It has no effect on modern browsers.

To limit the styles to devices with a **screen** and whose min and max width is known, you can chain the media features to the screen media type:

```
screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px)
```

For further guidance you can check [MDN website by clicking here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)