# Force a responsive site to render in a certain resolution

Tags: css, media

I am currently working on a new responsive website with several breakpoints. Between those breakpoints the layout should be flexible to always display as nice as possible on every device.

If a user views the page with a classic desktop browser i want to force the desktop version of the page and prevent the responsiveness.

Reason why is the lack of responsive ads which currently exist in germany.

Anyone has a clue for me how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `max-device-width` rather than `max-width`, which targets the viewport size rather than the device screen size.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 1024px) {
   /* Styles */
}
```

You can also target retina displays:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
   /* Styles */
}
```

Edit: See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Start by having two stylesheets. One responsive and one non-responsive. If it's a desktop user then load the non responsive and vise versa for mobile users

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 400px)" href="mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 401px)" href="desktop.css" />
```

Comment: this does not solve the issue properly. imagine a user with a desktop browser coming to the page with the window resized to 350px. the media query above will make the client load the wrong stylesheet