# How to display separate images for desktop and mobile browser using CSS?

Tags: html, image, css

http://tynesideelectrical.co.uk/

In this website displaying a phone number banner on header.
i need to display a 'click to call' image instead of this number banner while browsing from mobile device.

using with CSS.

Any hope. ?

Comment: Google 'media queries'

Comment: Instead of the `<img>` tag on the page, you could just set it as a background image, and then change the background image on the different device widths using the media-query.

Answer (score 3):

Using CSS, you can embed images via the `background-image` property and then combine it with media queries to load different images on desktop and mobile.

```
/* For desktop */
@media (min-width: 721px) {
  .header {
    background-image: url('img/desktop.png');
  }
}

/* For mobile */
@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .header {      
     background-image: url('img/mobile.png');
  }
}
```

Comment: My phone has a `max-width` of 980px. You'd be better using `max-device-width` instead and setting that to around 480px.

Comment: Check out this answer that says not to use `max-device-width` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500836/should-i-use-max-device-width-or-max-width

Answer (score 0):

Media Query's are your friend here!

You might want to look into:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

It checks the device/monitor, and according to that you change the styling.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can use simple

```
@media handheld {
    /* rules for mobile phone */    
}
@media screen {
    /* rules for computers */   
}
```

but (new) smartphones make a pretense of they are normal computers and will not react on handheld.

There's no exact way … you can only identify phone by smaller resolution (but seems that not for a long time)