# Is a CSS Pixel Ratio value stored on its OS?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

Are CSS Pixel Ratio values stored on each OS? Or browsers calculate the value by the ppi value or something?
If it is stored on its OS, is there any ways to change the value?

Searching for this question, I've found some people says something like "device reports it" but I still want to make sure if the value is stored on its OS and I could change the value.

Information that I've found..
[what exactly is device pixel ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785643/what-exactly-is-device-pixel-ratio)
[How are CSS pixel ratios determined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584634/how-are-css-pixel-ratios-determined)

Comment: Do you want to change the CSS pixel / hardware pixel ratio (e.g. it now uses 3 hardware pixels per px, and you want to change that), or do you want to make your device believe it has a different size (say it has a 6" screen at 367dpi and you want to make it think it's a 10" screen at 220dpi)?

Comment: @MrLister All I want to know is if CSS Pixel Ratio values are stored on each OS or not.  In another word, how a browser could know the value. Knowing If the value is able to be changed or not is just for gaining a better understanding of it.