# Firefox not using CSS for smaller size screens

Tags: css, firefox

Ok I have two CSS files for my HTML page and Chrome uses both 1 for `800px` or less the other for `801px` or more but Firefox and i.e. don't use the smaller one, they just display the larger one regardless of screen size.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="big.css" text="text/css" media="screen and (min-device-width:801px)" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="small.css" text="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width:800px)" rel="stylesheet" />     
</head>
</html>

h1 {
   margin: 5%;
   text-align: center;
}
h2 {
   margin: 5%;
   text-align: center;
}
```

The CSS is for the small but it displays differently. Very new to this, help..

Comment: If you're testing on a desktop browser, don't use the min/max-device-width query. See if it works with `min-width` and `max-width`.

Comment: Thank you. What would i put as the max width on the big file?

Comment: its as if firefox is completly disregarding the second file

Comment: Use the same values. Just instead of `max-device-width`, use `max-width`. Same switch for `min`.  More details [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6747242/3597276) and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18500836/3597276).

Comment: I have made the change but now the small file when edited/changed show no change

Comment: How to change font size and other things for just opera/mozilla.? in this css file with out effecting chromes stuff?

Answer (score 1):

Like @Michael_B said: `min-width` and `max-width`, not `min/max-device-width`. You're not querying the width of the device; you're interested in the width of the viewport.

Using the same values (800px and 801px respectively) should work.

Comment: Thanks all for your responses, but now only the big (2000px -801px is being used). no changes seen when small file modified.

Comment: small file =800-1px

Comment: How to change font size and other things for just opera/mozilla.? in this css file with out effecting chromes stuff??