# What units are referenced by responsive web design breakpoints?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

When breakpoints are set in CSS for responsive web designs, media queries check the width of a device so that different layouts can be appropriately displayed. As I thought I understood it, the pixel units in the media queries were referencing the **rendered pixel resolutions** that we commonly see in device specs. For example, the iPhone 5 at `640 x 1136px` or the Nexus 5 at `1080 x 1920`.

But now I’m confused about whether breakpoints are instead meant to reference a device’s **points** (for iOS) or **density-independent pixels** (for Android).
This question largely stems from how I’ve often seen common breakpoints referenced, with buckets defined for phones, tablets, and then desktop screens. This, for instance, is from [Bootstrap’s documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/):

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 544px)
// No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap

// Small devices (landscape phones, 544px and up)
@media (min-width: 544px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

But wait a second. The Samsung Galaxy series has a few phones nowadays whose resolutions are `1440 x 2560`. With the breakpoints above, these higher-resolution phones would be treated like desktops, wouldn’t they? Even the iPhone 6 Plus would qualify as a desktop. That can’t be right.

And while I know it’s best practice to define breakpoints based on content and not the device, the Bootstrap example is representative of a seemingly widespread idea that there ought to be breakpoints for portrait phones, landscape phones, tablets, and desktops … but a single bucket for all portrait phones doesn’t make sense if we’re talking about [rendered pixels](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified), because there’s so much device size diversity in that category alone!

Finally, I also found [this kinda related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18500871), which encourages setting the viewport meta tag so that “the screen's width will **match the device independent pixels** and will ensure that all the different devices should scale and behave consistently.” (Emphasis is mine.) So to return to the Bootstrap example, even though the unit says `px`, it could actually be referring to `pts` or `dps`?

All of this – plus a parallel investigation of mine into the concept of designing in 1x to 4x for different screen densities – has got me completely spun around on what feels like it ought to be a basic issue. Am I making this out to be more complicated than it is? And `dps` and `pts` relevant only to native development and not responsive web design? **What units exactly are media query breakpoints referencing?**

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted, it's a perfectly normal question.

Answer (score 3):

From the very same post you referenced in your question:

> [**Stack Overflow**– “Should I use max-device-width or max-width?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500836/should-i-use-max-device-width-or-max-width/18500871#18500871)
>
> In terms of media queries, you will probably want to use `max-width` rather than `max-device-width`, since `max-width` will target the viewport (current browser window), whereas `max-device-width` will target the device's actual full screen size/resolution.

So to answer your question, pixel-based media queries– combined with the correct `<meta name=viewport>` tag settings –will reference *rendered* (as opposed to actual) pixels.

Comment: You can remove the part about em units, it's a confusing standard that has no use anymore since all modern browsers now set the viewport width correctly on zoom.

Comment: More info on the em unit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px TL;DR It's a unit that scales on the font-size change which is in most cases not needed. The issue (zooming) em solved in the past has been fixed for years.

Comment: agreed, ems are a bit off topic– my personal opinion, of course, but removing and updating now per these suggestions!