# Why Rem height is scaling in Chrome Device Emulation (and mobile devices)

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries, font-size

> **Please see my demo video:** https://youtu.be/8BQ_UgMGK2E

---

I'm convinced that `rem` is great for components, and `em` for sub-components, but seemingly my `height:5rem` is corresponding to something other than root `font-size:16px`

I cannot figure out why device / mobile emulation seems to scale the root font-size, as `rem` should be consistent at 16px, regardless of how many pixels are on the screen

1. Meta tag just says charset utf 8
2. `window.devicePixelRatio` is a consistent `2`

Comment: That does seem odd.. What does your viewport meta tag look like?

Comment: It's normal, just meta charset utf8

Comment: No.. It sounds like you don't have [a viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) meta tag specified... try adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`.

Comment: @JoshCrozier this fixed it, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above, you can resolve this by adding a [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) to the `head` element of your document.

For instance:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

In doing so, this allows you to control the width and scaling of the browser's viewport. If this tag has a `content` value of `width=device-width`, the screen's width will match the device independent pixels and will ensure that all the different devices should scale and behave consistently.

For more specific information, here is [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18500836/2680216) that I answered. The answer goes into more detail regarding the difference between `max-width` and `max-device-width`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as mentioned by Josh Crozier is to add

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

in the `index.html` `<head>` section