# Hiding div on mobile below a certain screen resolution

Tags: html, css

I want to hide a div on all devices with a screen resolution that is less than 1024. This is the div that adds the space after 3 images:

```
<div class="page-banners clearer">&nbsp;</div>
```

And this is the page:

http://m.theseolounge.co.uk/

and this is the code I am using:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width :1024px)
 {
 .page-banners
 {
  display: none !important;
 }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What compelled you to use max-device-width instead of max-width?

Comment: use `max-width` instead of `max-device-width`

Comment: Try using `visibility: hidden`

Comment: @Ajay - no , I see absolutely no reason for that

Comment: I can't find that code anywhere on your website... (error in the filepath?)

Comment: @MichaelCoker I have actually changed that to max-width and it worked!

Comment: @Shakamal awesome. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500836/should-i-use-max-device-width-or-max-width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have a `<meta>` viewport tag in the `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Don't use `!important` for the style, and use `max-width` instead of `max-device-width`, like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1024px){
  .page-banners {
    display: none;
  }
}
```