# max-width and and (orientation:landscape) media query does not work in real phones

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a confusion.
I have seen in many sites that using max-device-width is deprecated and I need to use max-width instead. So I need to hind a banner when in landscape mode and here is how I did it:

```
/*landscape*/
@media screen
and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)
{
    .hide-row-on-landscape {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

On dev tool in chrome it works like a charm but when I tests it in real iphone I can not see it working.
So I decided to use the following:

```
/*landscape*/
@media screen
and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape),
(max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)
{
    .hide-row-on-landscape {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

and it worked.
Now I am confused
if max-device-width is deprecated and shouldnot be used why max-width does not work in this scenario?
Also what is the best solution for what i am trying to do?

**Update

I know there are a lot of answers supporting max-width without device but non of them explain why max-width does not support orientation. So none of them  not answers my scenario: I need to use (orientation:landscape) and it seems that when it comes to this property max-width does not handle that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use max-device-width or max-width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500836/should-i-use-max-device-width-or-max-width)

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Actually it does not answer my scenario: I need to use (orientation:landscape) and it seems that when it comes to this property max-width does not handle that. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can simply use only this one:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1280px) {

}
```

it will work on all devices mobile + tabs + browsers(old, new).
why you need this (orientation:landscape)?

Comment: Because I need a different style in landscape and I do not want to use javascript for that

Comment: Yes you can get your require style using this meida query for mobile devices without using javascript.