# CSS: Media query is invoked when it clearly should not

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'll make it simple:

This is the **only code** in my sample project's entire scope that turns the background to red.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {
        background: red;    
    }
```

I cannot explain why I'm seeing a red background in this Chrome responsive simulator when the `min-width` is clearly below `768px`:

[image]

Comment: show us a (non)working example of this actually happening. (snippet, or link to site)

Comment: This answer should solve your problem (meta viewport tag): https://stackoverflow.com/a/18500871/7497763

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't replicate the issue. Given you said it is the only code, shouldn't there be a CSS class selector?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .someClassName {
      background: red;    
    }
}
```

Comment: or (probably) not a class, but `body`

Answer (score -1):

The answer is that I was using `min-width` instead of using `min-device-height` -- Once I switched to `device-height` vs. `height` - things started working.

Comment: Regarding device-height - See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-height