# height of element changes when changing mobile orientation

Tags: css

You can see the problem here accessing the site on your mobile (for me Iphone):If you go back to portrait after going to landscape.

http://machinas.com/wip/stradviarius/startpage/

the height of the blocks `<section class="block">` change height when changing the mobile orientation between portrait and landscape. It's css is set as:

```
.block {
    height: 50vw;
    width: 50%;
}
```

How can I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: [`vw` units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) are relative to the viewport width. When the width of the viewport changes, so does the relative height of `.block`. How does your desired functionality differ?

Comment: It's when you go to landscape then go back to portrait, portrait is wrong.

Comment: What is wrong about it? Does it stay the same as landscape when you go back to portrait? Might be similar to [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747644/mobile-orientation-change-not-applying-css). Or maybe [this one](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/a_fix_for_the_ios_orientationchange_zoom_bug/).