# Catch recalculated styles after orientation of device changed

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

I am working on mobile device app written in JavaScript. I am wondering if there is an option to get new value of element's width when orientation was changed. I know that I can use             `$(window).on("orientationchange",function(){});` to catch moment when orientation is changing, but css values are not recalculated here. I also try to use [attrchange](https://github.com/meetselva/attrchange) plugin, but orientation changes do not causes attrchange event.

Does someone overcome this issue?

Comment: Why don't use `$(window).on("resize",function(){});`

Comment: With `console.log($('body').width())` I am getting narrower width when my device is in horizontal position and wider in opposite case, but I am looking for new, recalculated values...

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is css value use media query:

```
/* portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* portrait-specific styles */
}
/* landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* landscape-specific styles */
}
```

Comment: I also tried this but without effect :/ Lastly and sadly I use a time interval function with some code inside to catch moment of awaited change.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747644/mobile-orientation-change-not-applying-css