# Android browser media queries break on rotation

Tags: css, media-queries

I am experience strange behavior on my site with the default Android browser, with regards to the CSS media queries I am using.

The problem is such that everything works fine, but as soon as I rotate my device to landscape, it picks up and applies the CSS for wider screens; however when I then rotate back to portrait, the CSS for wider screens is still applied. If I rotate my phone landscape, then back to portrait, then refresh, the correct thinner screen CSS is once again applied.

Example CSS:

```
.box {
  width:100%;
}

@media
 screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:599px),
 screen and (min-device-width:480px) and (max-device-width:599px)
{
  .box {
    width:33.333%
  }
}
```

Diagram to better explain the issue:

[image: graphic displaying media query issue]
This only seems to be happening on the default Android browser, it happens with no other browser.

**Justification for complicated look of media queries**:
They seem to work best across all browsers, I've had issues with IE9 when just using one 'min-width' statement.

I also thought I would include the `<meta>` tags I am using, they are:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
```

Can anyone tell me what is causing this strange Android behavior? Is this some sort of bug?

Thanks for reading.

**NOTE** Scrollbars must be present for it to act like this

### Update #1

Using the following media queries, everything works as expected:

```
.box {
  width:100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:480px) {
  .box {
    width:33.333%;
  }
}
```

I'm presuming there is some issue with how Android deals with the min/max-device-width options or they are conflicting.

Comment: Delete the question if you already have your answer or post that as the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I was incorrectly making use of the min/max-width and min/max-device-width statements (they were conflicting with each other), this became obvious after [reading the accepted answer to this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web).

It seems min/max-width refers to the target display area size and min/max-device-width refers to the entire devices rendering area (its screen).

The correct CSS to use in this case is:

```
.box {
  width:100%; 
}

@media screen and (min-width:480px) {
  .box {
    width:33.333%;
  }
}
```