# Media queries doesn't work

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Does anyone know why my media queries code doesn't work ?

```
 <div class="box"></div>
```

```
 .box {
     background-color: red;
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
 } 

 @media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px)  {
     .box {border: 5px solid blue;}
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N9mYU/

Comment: device-width is deprecated now.

Answer (score 15):

You would use `(max-width: 768px)` instead of `(max-device-width: 768px)`. See the difference between `max-device-width`/`max-width` explained [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web).

Add a viewport if you want the media query to work on mobile devices:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Huv24/)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .box {
        border: 5px solid blue;
    }
}
```

Further reading: [A pixel is not a pixel/Viewport width and screen width (mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for this issue is you define your `@media` queries before styling your element in CSS file so you should always **put `@media` queries at the end of your CSS file!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this, at the top of the page, this is for smartphone responsitivity

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

Answer (score -4):

Sorry folks but this question just became moot: Firefox Dev edition just did an upgrade and changed how the device screens are presented: you can no longer select screen size by pixel using a drop down box; you now have to select the device name which will have its dimensions displayed.

I've long had problems when Firefox has issued an update while I have the browser open.

The regular Firefox browser with firebug is now more responsive. Some of issues I have been dealing with is that when I set a limit such as "min-width 320px" FDE only performs the change at a larger min, say 380px. This does not change in the updated edition.

Comment: This question did not become moot. You can still resize your browser without using Dev tools. Nor does this question ask about dev tools. The original question was because of `max-device-width` vs. `max-width`. FF Dev has had the device dropdown for a couple versions now.