# CSS Different between (max-width:320px) and (max-device-width:320px)

Tags: css

What's the difference?

```
(max-width:320px) and (max-device-width:320px)
```

I try the max-width i think its only work on window resize

And the max-device-width only works on mobile screen?
Its true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would **Google** or **search** on Stackoverflow, you would find this page:

[What is the difference between max-device-width and max-width for mobile web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web)

Look what it says to you:

`max-width` is the width of the target display area, e.g. the browser

`max-device-width` is the width of the device's entire rendering area, i.e. the actual device screen

Same goes for `max-height` and `max-device-height` naturally.