# How to detect the media query in use?

Tags: javascript, css

How to detect which the media query is in use,like"

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
.menubar ul li a {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    color:rgb(148,168,148)  ;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 13px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 400;
    font-size:14px;
}
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
.menubar ul li a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size:19px  ;
}
}
```

I just want a method to get the matched media query string,return "@media (max-width: 979px)" or "@media (max-width: 1200px)" in this case.

Comment: What if they both match? Anything that is (max-width: 979px) is necessarily also (max-width: 1200px). In particular the way you are ordering your rules means that the padding, text-align and font-size declarations in your first rule are completely redundant as they will never be used.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnzdcguv/). As pointed out in the comment, both styles will be applied, whereas the overlapping styles (for instance, font-size, text-align etc... that are common for both CSS styles) will be overwritten by the other (based on their ordering in the style sheet).

For simplification and demo, I have applied the styles to `a` tag and used the following HTML code,

```
<a href="google.com">Test link</a>
```

Below is the style applied for the `anchor` tag based on your style. You can check this in your page using developer tools from browser (I have used FireBug)

[image: JSFiddle]

**Note:** If you are targeting devices based on their screen size, you should consider using the max-device-width instead. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web)