# Media query max-width 992px not working on ipad landscape view

Tags: html, css, ipad, media-queries

When I look on my iPad on landscape view, the CSS Media query `max-width: 992px` is not working and the responsive layout is still visible (but on desktop it breaks at 992px). Any help is appreciated.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

My CSS media queries:

```
.responsive_button{display:none;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
   .responsive_button{display:block;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

iPad resolution is:

- 768px by 1024px (Portrait)
- 1024px by 768px (Landscape)

If you want to target ipad's different orientation use the below media queries mind that the orientation is specified as well.

*iPad in Portrait*

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

*iPad in Landscape:*

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

Comment: But using the **max-device-width** instead of **max-width** i don't think i will be able to test it in my desktop browser when i resize the window. Can i use your example in combination with my media querries ?

Comment: And how come bootstrap is not using the **max-device-width** and no one ever complained, cause my media querries are pretty similar.

Comment: Yes you can use these media queries in combination with yours. I thought the problem was with iPad. The above solution suggests where you should place your CSS code for iPad devices.

Comment: Yes is related to iPad as i thought that my example media queries are applied to all devices/browsers. It means that every time i will design a new theme i will apply a separate media queries for iPads ?

Comment: It depends on what devices you are designing for.

Comment: Since is a responive theme, no matter the device is, it should work,right? Same as using the bootstrap framework instead, but they are not using the **max-device-width** ..that's why is confusing to me.

Comment: Yes it should work, look this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web

Comment: Hi @Denis if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

An iPad's resolution is 768px by 1024px, this means in landscape mode, it is 1024px wide. The media query will not be active as 992px fits onto the 1024px wide screen.

As a general rule, iPads in landscape mode should just be treat as desktop screens.

Comment: I don't think i understand or i didn't explained my self enough..If the 992px fits onto the 1024px ,than why i still see the responsive layout? Cause it supposed to be visible at max 992px.