# Media Query in External CSS File

Tags: html, css

I am modifying my CSS3/HTML5 site to work with different Medial Queries.

The site pages are in the Root directory. The CSS files are within a folder in the root directory called css.

Within the HEAD tags of my page, I have one CSS file for the default stuff and then I have another one for iPad in an external CSS file called ipad.css

When I am in the Developer Tools within Google Chrome, it doesn't seem to be applying the rules within the ipad.css file. I know this because I am wanting to change the text size of an element and it is not changing. Nothing is happening.

This is what I have within the HEAD tags:

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" title="Default Styles">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ipad.css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 768px)" title="iPad Styles">
```

According to the Google Chrome Developer Tools, an iPad width is 768px. I have referenced this within the link tag. Any ideas or suggestions welcome.

Comment: You need to learn **now** how to **EDIT** your question. You have put all the additional information into **ANSWERS**!

Answer (score 0):

Use `max-width: 768px` rather than `max-device-width: 768px`.

Also, remember to specify a [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) in the head section of your html.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Also, you might want to check

> [What is the difference between max-device-width and max-width for mobile web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web)

Also, keep in my you're not targeting devices, you're targeting resolutions.

Another possible source of your problem might be that you are using less specific selectors in your `ipad.css`. Don't forget that the styles from your `default.css` are also used on resolutions lower than 769px!

To test this, put this css rule on the very top of your `ipad.css`:

```
* { display: none !important; }
```

If your site vanishes then, your stylesheet **is** loaded and applied.

Comment: I tried that and nothing happened still. I even changed the color of the font to see if it would change for testing and nothing happened.

Comment: I tried that and nothing happened for me. I even went to change the font color to see if the css file is being read and the color stayed the same. No change. I have a div class called banner-textoverlay with a p tag within, so in my css file, I wrote the following for testing purposes:

Comment: Please add this information in your question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the max-width as well and the style isn't applying. Even if I change the font-color of the text within the div class (p tag), nothing is happening.

As an example, I have a div class called **banner-textoverlay** so, in my ipad.css file, I wrote the following to see if it would change the text color and nothing happens at all.

```
.banner-textoverlay p {
    font-color:#000000;
}
```

Comment: `font-color` does not exist. Use `color`. Also, put this in your **question**, **not** as an answer!