# Why isn't max-width and width: 100% working?

Tags: html, css

The problem is with my [blog](http://www.vkcreativework.blogspot.com). So I can't put code here. Ok, if you see, when you open this blog in desktop browser, and decrease the width of browser, the content of the blog **shrinks**, i.e., width is decreased (it's not scrolling in horizontal dicrection). This is because of **width: 100%** and **max-width** properties used.

But when you open this blog in your **phone**'s browser, it doesn't follow them, although screen resolution of mobile phones are less than desktop browser. Why doesn't the content shrink? Am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: I think it's the problem with the browser! Don't use %, instead set the width to maximum device width! Here's one link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web

Answer (score 0):

The max-width should contains pixels(px) instead of a percentage symbol(%).

1) Add this to your head of the file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

2)Try out media queries such as

```
<style type="text/css">
/* default styles here for older browsers. 
   I tend to go for a 600px - 960px width max but using percentages
*/
@media only screen and (min-width:960px){
    /* styles for browsers larger than 960px; */
}
@media only screen and (min-width:1440px){
    /* styles for browsers larger than 1440px; */
}
@media only screen and (min-width:2000px){
    /* for sumo sized (mac) screens */
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width:480px){
   /* styles for mobile browsers smaller than 480px; (iPhone) */
}
@media only screen and (device-width:768px){
   /* default iPad screens */
}
/* different techniques for iPad screening */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* For portrait layouts only */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* For landscape layouts only */
}
</style>
```

Comment: Did you try adding what I said on the header and then the rest of the thing below ?

Answer (score -1):

You should use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in your page html's `<head>` to make your blog mobile friendly