# Device-width and screen.width & window.innerWidth

Tags: html, css

What the `device-width` CSS3 property refers to? Is it `screen.width` or rather `window.innerWidth`?

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html

Answer (score 0):

```
window.innerWidth
```

exactly, which work only for device

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#device-width)

> Describes the width of the output device (meaning the entire screen or page, rather than just the rendering area, such as the document window).

And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6747471/2571493):

> max-device-width is the width of the device's entire rendering area, i.e. the actual device screen

Therefore it's `screen.width`.

Comment: So `screen.width` is always the same (constant) for concrete mobile device?

Comment: @Mulligun81 No! The user can rotate the device so that the width becomes the height.

Comment: Ok i understand. Can You explain me then why does setting `height=device-height` viewport property doesn't work - `window.innerHeight` always reports the same vale while setting `width=device-width` is reflected by `window.innerWidth`?

Comment: @Nhan Can You answer my question?

Comment: Sorry @Mulligun81, I'm afraid I can't, I'm not sure about this.