# what should I use (min-device-width) and (min-width)?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm doing some testing on the RWD (Responsive Web Design) and was seraching for the most common breakpoints. I came across this:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
body {
background-color: #7763a5; }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
body {
background-color: #011C40; }
}

@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
body {
background-color: #3957FC; }
}
```

I tried to resize the window of my browser (using Chrome) and found out that none of the styles takes effect except for the one with the `(min-width : 1224px)` attribute.

Why does that happen and how shall I test for portable devices styles? Also, is it OK to write the conditional statement for the other devices like that?

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {

}
```

Because the last on aimed at desktop is just written without the "device" part, mentioned in the other statements.

I reviewed this question [difference between max-width and max-device-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web). To be fair, I kind of got something out of the answer, but still do not know why my browser on my desktop refuses to apply the styles when I resize the window.

Comment: If you use max-device-width, when you change the size of the browser window on your desktop, the CSS won't change, because your desktop doesn't change size.

If you use max-width, when you change the size of the browser window on your desktop, you might be shown mobile-orientated styling, such as touch-friendly elements and menus and that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@media (max-width: px) {}
@media (min-width: px) {}
```

For any size