# Resposive Mobile and display: none - Wordpress - Visual Composer

Tags: css, iphone, wordpress, responsive, visual-composer

Hello i have a problem with hide one row (exactly background) on mobile and tablet device i try give class to row : “none” and add css but this dont work on mobile

http://scr.hu/0wj8n/x00rp

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 900px){
  .none {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 900px){
  .none {
    background-image: none !important;
}
}
```

Comment: JSfiddle please. Also, saying it doesn't work isn't specific enough. Write what you expect to happen, and what happens.

Comment: i wanna off this div(exactly i mean background) with class "none" on mobile device and i cant :/ i use Visual Composer for Wordpress.

Comment: SO users may be fluent in other languages, but the site is in English. If you can, get a friend to write the question more clearly for you. What other language do you know BTW?

Comment: I corrected :) sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work on an actual phone/tablet. It doesn't work in these emulators because the `max-device-width` refers to the **device width**, not the width of the iframe window. In the emulator, the device is your computer, which almost certainly has a larger physical screen width than 900px. So, for development, use `max-width` instead:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
  .none {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
  .none {
    background-image: none !important;
  }
}
```

On production, feel free to use `max-device-width`. More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6747242/6941627).