# Prevent running of mobile specific media query(landscape) on desktop view(landscape)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

First of all I am really sorry for the title of the question as I wasn't able to figure out on how to describe my problem, so this is why I used such title.

Right now I am starter in using media queries and I am using them on my practice project for its responsiveness and I want to apply an orientation lock on that project. Like, the project is compatible on the mobile portrait view but it is not available on the mobile landscape view.

I have applied the following code for the orientation lock, but the problem is that when the browser window is resized and when it matches the screen resolution, the lock applies. I don't want the lock to get applied on the desktop view.

There is a way which is by using device-width but that has been deprecated by mozilla. So, is there any way to resolve this issue with only min-width or something else?

Please let me know if you are unable to understand.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"/>
    <style>
    #div-2{
    display:none;
    }
    @media screen and(min-width:320px) and (orientation:landscape){
    #div-1{
    display:none;
    }
    #div-2{
    display:block;
    }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div-1"><p>Orientation lock not applied.</p></div>
    <div id="div-2"><p>Orientation lock applied.</p></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry my friend. The post which you have shared is not according to my question.

Comment: you want div-1 visible when orientation mode is landscape right?

Comment: Yes I want the div-1 visible in the landscape view, but when the landscape view is of Desktop based. But on the mobile landscape view I want the div-1 to disappear and div-2 to show up.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i understand now replace the code hope this is useful for you:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
    <style>

        @media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (orientation:landscape) {
            #div-1 {
                display: block;
}
#div-2 {
                display: none;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 961px) and (orientation:landscape) {
#div-2 {
display: none;
}
#div-1{
display:block;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div-1">
<p>Orientation lock not applied.</p>
</div>
<div id="div-2>
        <p>Orientation lock applied.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry my friend. Your answer didn't work for me. May be I am unable to explain my question to you and others properly. I am really sorry for that, but I'll try to explain it again.
I want the "div-2" to show up when the webpage is in landscape view of mobile device but not to show up in desktop's landscape view. 

There is a solution towards my problem using device-width property, but mozilla has deprecated that property and suggests not to use it further. So I want to know is there any way to resolve this issue using min-width or height?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not any strange thing.

You write this media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (orientation:landscape) {
        #div-1 {
            display: none;
        }

        #div-2 {
            display: block;
        }
    }
```

That contains desktop. So in desktop div-1 is hide and div-2 is visible.

If you want this media query works only for mobile you must use **max-width**

that filters screens that are larger than what you want(**Desktop**). It means that styles are not for desktop. 
This media query works on size of browser and if you want to filter some **Devices size**  independent of browser width you must use this media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 320px)
```

Comment: quite correct but, what about the browser window resizing problem? When someone resizes their browser window(which people use mostly to check the responsiveness of the site) and it comes to a specific width suppose 500px then the media query will run. But I don't want that. I want to run it only for mobile device.

Comment: So you can use 'max-device-width' that only works on width of device. There is no different what size the browser has. Then media query does not run by browser resizing.

Comment: We can use max-device-width and min-device-width, and they have already resolved my question but those properties have been discontinued by Mozilla and they do not recommend to use them further. So that is why I am searching either an alternative or a way to use min-width like device width.

Comment: I believe that what i said is the only way. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web

Comment: Yes, this is one of many ways and mostly used. But, when browsers in the future stops to recognize max-device-width and max-device-height(as Mozilla has already discontinued them) then these properties will not work.

No issues my friend. You tried your best. Thank you for all your support.

I think I need to use JavaScript to target the devices and to implement my requirement.

Comment: See this that i wrote with 'max-device-width' with your firefox: http://drmjenab.com/index11.aspx#. With Shift+Ctrl+M you can see resposive view of firefox.