# Centering text on mobile only

Tags: css, classname

I'm pretty new to advanced CSS. I have a custom heading section which i want to make centered on mobile only. I have added a class name and the following code but nothings happened.

```
.mobile-text {
  text-align: right;
}

@media (max-device-width: 600px) {
  .mobile-text {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

[This](https://dev5.runforthehills.com/) is the homepage of this site and the paragraph is the following:

> REAL ESTATE THAT CHALLENGES NORMS & ELEVATES EXPECTATIONS. THIS IS COLOURFUL THINKING IN A BLACK AND WHITE WORLD.

Comment: Change `max-device-width` to `max-width`

Comment: 1. You wrote the class name wrong in the HTML class attribute of that element. 2. The element has _inline styles_ that overwrite `text-align`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class on the website is `.mobile-text`, and it should be `mobile-text` - The `.` is only used in selectors to say that the following text is a class name

Also, your inline styles on the element ( `style=font-size: 35px... etc` ) is overwriting your changes - you can use `!important` to handle this lazily

```css
.mobile-text {
  text-align: right !important;
}

@media (max-device-width: 600px) {
  .mobile-text {
    text-align: center !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`max-device-width` will target the width of the entire device area (i.e the device screen). Instead use `max-width`, which will target the width of the entire browser area.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .mobile-text {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

**Note:** `device-width` queries are [deprecated](http://Media%20Queries%20Level%204%20specification%20draft).

Answer (score 0):

Your media query is not working on desktop if you are check in desktop view.

And also your `class` declaration is wrong please remove `.` from `mobile-text`. :)

```
max-width is the width of the target display area, e.g. the browser

max-device-width is the width of the device's entire rendering area, i.e. the actual device screen
```

Please use @media all and (max-width: 600px){}

For more details please visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web)

Hope it will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

When I check the `html` of your page I can see the `class=""` of this `<h4>`:

```html
class="vc_custom_heading .mobile-text wpb_animate_when_almost_visible wpb_right-to-left right-to-left vc_custom_1580217248411 wpb_start_animation animated"
```

In your `css` you want to manipulate it using the `.mobile-text` class. Problem here is that you define this class in your `html` using `.mobile-text`. That's actually wrong, you need to define it with only `mobile-text` like this:

```html
class="vc_custom_heading mobile-text wpb_animate_when_almost_visible wpb_right-to-left right-to-left vc_custom_1580217248411 wpb_start_animation animated"
```

The `.` is actually a css selector for a class like `#` is a selector for an id.