# Navbar does not stick to the top in mobile

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make navbar responsive, but it does not stick to the top when I scroll down as you can see the picture below, it just stays at the top and disappears as i scroll down just like a normal div (I scrolled a little bit from the top) 
what am I missing ?

my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/sbayrak/suatbayrak-portfolio-master)

EDIT: there is no problem with desktop version

my HTML of navbar

```
<div
    className='navbar'
    style={{ transition: 'ease-in-out 0.5s', backgroundColor: bgColor }}
  >
    <div className='navbar-wrapper'>
      <div className='left'>
        <img src={myLogo} alt='logo' />
        <span id='name'>Suat Bayrak</span>
      </div>
      <div className='right'>
        <i className='fas fa-bars' onClick={(e) => menuFunc(e)}></i>
        <ul className={showMenu ? 'active' : ''}>
          <li>
            <NavLink to='/' exact activeClassName='active'>
              Home
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to='/about' exact activeClassName='active'>
              About
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            {' '}
            <NavLink to='/portfolio' exact activeClassName='active'>
              Porfolio
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to='/contact' exact activeClassName='active'>
              Contact
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

here is my CSS

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 767px) {
.navbar {
position: fixed;
z-index: 199;
top: 0;
}
.navbar .navbar-wrapper {
width: 100%;
}
.navbar .navbar-wrapper .left {
border: 1px solid white;
width: 25%;
}
.navbar .navbar-wrapper .left #name {
font-size: 24px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: make a reproducible example, or add html, pls

Comment: added now, btw I am using React

Comment: Your code works for me

Comment: what might be the my problem? before this, my div under that was showing half, after i fixed that, this problem started to occur

Comment: EDIT: I tried on Firefox and its working just fine... i dont know whats up with Chrome, I have faced such a issues on chrome before

Answer (score 0):

You are using `max-device-width` and the device you are looking at has a `max-device-width` which is higher than 767px, the upper limit in the `@media` query.

You can read about the difference here:
[What is the difference between max-device-width and max-width for mobile web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web)

Comment: I didnt quite catch the solution, i made them into `max-width` but im facing with the same problem

Comment: There are multiple things to change with your code. Why do you have a ```<div id="root"``` ? Why are you using classes like id? You should have ```<main>``` and ```<footer>``` instead of ```<div class="main"``` and ```"footer"```.

Comment: i forgot to mention, i am using React and i just came with `create-react-app`

Comment: Is all this in the same component? Navbar or Header should be it's own component, it should be a ```<nav>``` element and you could wrap it in a ```<header>``` element if you make a component for the header... I think you need to study HTML and CSS before learning Reactjs...

Comment: I think we should focus on the question rather than making such a "suggestions". anyway thank you for your answers