# Media queries makes website responsive. But it doesn't only when I am dragging my browser

Tags: css, user-interface, sass, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a website that is fully responsive for all devices. When I am testing the responsiveness in devtools on chrome, all the breakpoints and the UI works perfectly. But when I am NOT in devtools and I am simply dragging my browser width, the breakpoints do not trigger.

This may not seem much of a big deal, but when recruiters are testing for website responsiveness, I don't think they pull up devtools to test. I think they just non-full screen the browser and drag the side of it to adjust the width for responsive testing.
I am using React with SCSS and solely using media queries in SCSS files for responsiveness. No hooks.

Here are some examples of my media queries.

```css
//
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 813px) 
and (max-device-width: 1080px) {
    .content-landing {
        .hider {
            h2 {
                font-size: $fsLandingText-tablet;

                .link,
                a {
                    font-size: $fsLandingText-tablet;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Phone portrait
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 320px) 
and (max-device-width: 812px) 
and(orientation: portrait) {
    .content-landing {
        .hider {
            h2 {
                font-size: $fsLandingText-phone;
                .link,
                a {
                    font-size: $fsLandingText-phone;
                }
            }
        }

        .line {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `min-width` and `max-width` on your media queries.

According to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6996549/6340965), `max-device-width` is fixed and it doesn't matter how you resize your window. When you use devtools to emulate smaller sizes, it sends its emulated device information, therefore it's working.

Comment: I'm so dumb. That makes sense. Thank you!!

Comment: @Jae Glad I could help. If my answer solves your problem, be sure to mark is as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yup! Just gotta wait 10 mins after post. Will do soon as possible. Thanks again!